# Kafka Consumer In .Net Core

Tags: asp.net-web-api, apache-kafka, microservices, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-platform

I want to use Kafka as message broker in our microservice based project. What is the best practice for implementing consumers ? Should we implement in WebApi as background service with adding hosted services or standalone console application ? Because of the infinite loop for listening queues I have doubts to use in API project for performance and scalibility reasons. In spite of that, I have to use models and classes in WebApi. For easy scaling, it is better to use a dedicated thread for a consumer and use console application. I wonder if there is any best practice or example to implement Kafka consumer in .Net Core ?

Comment: How are your apps hosted? on-premises? cloud? webbased?

Comment: We are using dedicated servers on cloud for apps. Apps will be web based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within a web application, you should make background worker threads to handle [consumer instances](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet).

Infinite poll loops are required if you want to continually process Kafka records.

Comment: I'm curious whether a HostedService background is common practice or not?

Comment: @SaherAhwal I dont know the internals of ASP.NET, so what do you mean?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: @SaherAhwal What does that have to do with Kafka? There is no need to have anything like that because Kafka natively has a polling continuous loop. I meant threads, not workers

Comment: it might because Kafka Confluent client doesn't have ConsumeAsync. no?